# The best model to analyse this data set: Comparing bacteria communities within calves

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, model, biostatistics

The design is like this: I have 18 calves in the experiment, and all these calves were divided into 3 groups with 6 calves in each group. The 6 calves in group 1 were euthanized at the end of the first week (week 1) of birth, the 6 calves in group 2 were euthanized after 3 weeks, and the other 6 calves in group 3 were euthanized after 6 weeks of birth. After the euthanization, samples (different types of samples: digesta and content) were collected from different gut regions (cecum, colon and rectum).

I should say that the calves in group 1 were only fed on whole milk, the calves in group 2 were fed on whole milk during the first week after birth, and after this, they were fed on whole milk and starter until the 3th week. Finally, the calves in group 3 were also fed on whole milk during the first week after birth, and then fed on milk and starter from the 2nd week to the 6th week after birth. After euthanizing the animals, I collected the tissues and contents samples from each calf in the different groups, and measured the quantity of four different species of bacteria to see the establishment of these communities during the first weeks of life in calves.

The purpose of this study is to investigate the differences of the four species of bacteria (in terms of quantity) among cecum, colon and rectum, and also to see if the types of samples (content or tissue) are involved in. Finally, I would like to know if the bacteria species found in the different regions of the gut (cecum, colon and rectum) and in the sample types (content or tissue)  are affected by the age (weeks after birth) and by the type of food (as described before) that the calves received during their life.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! You should think about a more informative title, fornow I will edit the title.